# Shortcut for redo in vim

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

In vim,

```
u = undo  
r = replace
```

Is there one key shortcut for redo ?

`ctrl + r` is a two key stroke (in my thinking),
and I often hit the wrong combination (I just recently switch to Mac)

Or is it possibile to map my own key stroke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course:

```
:nmap r <c-r>
```

But I strongly recommend against you using "r" as your mapped key.

Comment: noted, but i actually hardly use the replace

Comment: That should be *:nnoremap*  just in case someday ajreal remaps c-r to some other function.

Answer (score 0):

You could map one of the F-keys for redo by putting the following in your .vimrc

```
:map <F2> ^R
```

You can enter those special characters ( and ^R) by pressing ^V (ctrl-v) first.

For more details on entering special characters, :help i_CTRL-V